# NullReferenceException while getting properties from session object

Tags: asp.net, nullreferenceexception

I have created a class with name `Examination`, in this class I have a method with name `Get Question()`, in `take exam` when i am creating object of `Examination` and  Run Application it gives following error.

`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
Source Error: 


Line 18:         Examination e = (Examination)Session["questions"];
Line 19:         // display data
Line 20:         lblSubject.Text = e.sname;
Line 21:         lblQno.Text = e.curpos + 1 + "/" + e.SIZE;
Line 22:         lblCtime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Comment: Is the exception thrown at line 20?

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly yes on line 20

Comment: Seems like `e` is null, first check whether `Session["questions"]` contains data and if it is possible to cast it to `Examination`.

Comment: You know that line 18 does not create an object but reads it from the session, right?

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly i am creating object of Examination But Give red color ErrorLine without discription Examination e=new Examination();

Comment: There error must be displayed as you try to compile the code.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably `Session["questions"]` does not contain a value, and returns `null`. It is perfectly valid to cast `null` to a reference type, but the exception occurs where you try to access properties of it.

You should test if it's null, for instance:

```
Examination e = (Examination)Session["questions"];
if (e == null)
{
    lblSubject.Text = "Your session has expired";
}
```

(If I'm wrong, and `e` actually contains a reference to an `Examination` object, then it's `lblSubject` that's `null`)

Comment: if e null then what to do

Comment: When your Session (20 minutes per default iirc) times out, e is gong to be null. In this case, you need to reinitalize the session. There are event handlers for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx

Comment: As mentioned Session["questions"] is probably null. Its always a good practice to check for null before using any object specially if its returned from a different class/source (even if it can never be null). What if the implementation of the other class/source changes in future? Its just safe to check.